# dual entries in Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

boot-info is below.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KpTgxY5pTw/

In grub menu, the screen stops when i enter the Ubuntu. (16.04)

so i enter the advanced options for ubuntu, then there are 6 options.

1. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-41-generic
2. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-41-generic (upstart)
3. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-41-generic (recovery mode)
4. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-36-generic
5. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-36-generic (upstart)
6. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-36-generic (recovery mode)

if I enter number 1, it stops.
I didn't try number2. If I enter number3, i just resume twice. Finally the ubuntu is booted. Should i do this all the time when i boot the ubuntu?

Also, I did tried the 4 , it won't booted. Lastly, number 6 boot the ubuntu, but it can't shut down(turn off) the ubuntu( error occurs).

The interesting thing is that if I install chrome in 41 version, (by booting recovery mode-->resume-->resume)  chrome is also installed in 36 version of ubuntu.

Anyone know the solution, please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does Windows boot from grub menu? What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Your menu is just the different versions of the kernel, but same system, so software installed like Chrome would be in all of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering :)  yes, Window has no problem in booting. Which brand/ model system are you asking?? ... Sorry.. I don't know much about the laptop. Why menu shows different versions of the kemel? And what is kemel? If they are same system, why I can't enter by 36 version??

Comment: If a no-name computer what CPU AMD or Intel. And what video, add in card or internal from CPU chip? The kernel is Linux, or the software that is the operating system. You should be able to boot any of the current kernels. You mentioned 16.04, but the 3.2 kernels are from 12.04 which has expired as beyond 5 year support for LTS versions.